# python iterate static method for class

Tags: python, types, python-typing

```py
import inspect


class Wrapper:
    @staticmethod
    def a():
        pass

    @staticmethod
    def b():
        pass


# print(inspect.getmembers(Wrapper, lambda x: inspect.isfunction(x)))
# print(inspect.getmembers(Wrapper, lambda x: inspect.ismethod(x)))
```

to use `Wrapper` as a module of static methods,
how can I obtain a list of `[a, b]`.

Comment: are you familiar with https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.FunctionType .   i.e. `isinstance(foo, types.FunctionType)`

Comment: @jsofri, cheers, haven't touch `types` before, I will dive deep into it.

Comment: @MechanicPig, cheers, but `print(inspect.getmembers(Wrapper, lambda member: isinstance(member, staticmethod)))` gives `[]`

Comment: `inspect.getmembers(Wapper, inspect.isfunction)` give me `[('a', <function Wapper.a>), ('b', <function Wapper.b>)]`. It seems to me that it works normally. If you only need the name, you can filter it yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`inspect.getmembers` internally uses `getattr` to get the members in the class, and during this process, `staticmethod` will be converted into the wrapped function, thus losing information.

If you want to get all the functions wrapped by `staticmethod`, the easiest way is to traverse the class dictionary and check it with `isinstance`:

```
>>> class Wrapper:
...     @staticmethod
...     def a():
...         pass
...     @staticmethod
...     def b():
...         pass
...
>>> [member.__func__
...  for member in vars(Wrapper).values()
...  if isinstance(member, staticmethod)]
[<function Wrapper.a at 0x79882bd160>,
 <function Wrapper.b at 0x79882bd1f0>]
```

This won't get the static methods in the base class. If necessary, you have to traverse each base class yourself. One possible method is as follows:

```
{name: member.__func__
 for base in reversed(Wrapper.mro()[:-1])
 for name, member in vars(base).items()
 if isinstance(member, staticmethod)}
```